# What AppDomain is used by classic ASP when instantiating .NET class?

Tags: .net, asp-classic

What happens (in terms of CLR) when the code on a classic ASP page creates an instance of  .NET class (marked as ComVisible, type library is registered)?

What AppDomain is used for the newly created instance? Does it have anything to do with the AppDomain of the ASP.NET application running on the same site?

Comment: what asp.net site? you only mention a classic asp site.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: @x0n  As I wrote in my question, quote, "ASP.NET application running on the same site". That is classic asp application and ASP.NET application both accessible from the same virtual path (for example root application). So I did mention ASP.NET application.

Comment: @ags where they appear logically in the virtual path have nothing to do with their memory models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each "application" (an asp.net or classic ASP site) in IIS runs in a win32 process, also known as an "application pool." Each application pool (process) may have zero or one version of the CLR loaded* (1.0,1.1,2.0,4.0) loaded into the process simultaneously. Each CLR instance, within a process, has at least one Application Domain, the unit of execution and isolation for .NET. When you instantiate a .NET component via a CCW (COM-callable wrapper) from classic ASP, the CLR is loaded into the application pool process that hosts that site, and a default appdomain is created *for that process*. The logical position in the URL path hierarchy is irrelevant because different segments can have different application pools.

That probably is a lot to take in, but I suggest reading up on IIS/WAS architecture and the CLR's process/appdomain/assembly relationships.

*The CLR 4.0 loader allows one or more versions of the CLR to be loaded into the same process

Comment: Thanks a lot. Two more questions.

Comment: 1. Why in your first sentence you wrote that "Each application in IIS runs in a win32 process" as though it is the only possible variant? Isn't it entirely possible to have win64 process when "Enable 32-bit Application" flag is turned off?

Comment: 2. Do I understand it right that the difference between ASP.NET and classic ASP site is that I can have any number of ASP.NET applications within a single application pool and each of them gets its personal app domain. But any number of classic ASP apps will be combined under single predefined app domain which is named (as I can  see in a debugger) "DefaultDomain". In other words, is there something specific to this DefaultDomain? What part of IIS/CLR is responsible, for example, for naming the domain(s) associated with classic ASP? That is why it is named exactly as it is?

Comment: The number of applications within has more to do with IIS and apppool settings.  In IIS you create an "application" and map it to an appool (a process with settings).  Multiple IIS applications can be mapped to the same apppool which is a process.  A process can have multiple appdomains (.net clr runtime concept) and the CLR creates a default one.

Comment: Thanks, @bryanmac. Sorry for the confusion but in the second question I asked specifically about the case when several classic asp applications are mapped to a single application pool. Let's assume each of this classic asp applications instantiate .NET objects via CCW. Will they get separate app domain for each? Just curious what the names for app domains will be in this case? DefaultDomain1, DefaultDomain2, something else?

Comment: @ags answer 1) many people refer to "win32" process as a synonym for "unmanaged." It may well be 64 bit.

Comment: answer 2) the first time the CLR is loaded into a process, a single appdomain is created and is called "default domain." You need at leaat one appdomain to run managed (.net) code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it out and check AppDomain.CurrentDomain

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.currentdomain.aspx

Then you can look at FriendlyName or Id to see or compare app domains.

EDIT:

You asked in the comment below who creates the appDomain and whether several ASP apps can share.  ASP runs inside IIS and if IIS6 or greater, an IIS application (that hosts ASP) is bound to an appPool.  If two asp/IIS apps are bound to the same appPool then they share the same process.  If not, they don't.  A process can have multiple appDomains.  When the asp site creates the .net object through COM the CLR runs that code.  The CLR creates the first appDomain in a process and it names it "DefaultDomain".  You can programmatically create others.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not answer my question. I saw that the domain is different from appDomain created for ASP.NET application and its name is "DefaultDomain". What I wanted to find is some explanations regarding how the domain is instantiated and why it is named like that. What if I have several classic ASP applications on the same IIS instance that instantiate .NET objects? Will I have several app domains named  "DefaultDomain" created in this case? I am interested in the  logic behind the process because I could not find any mentions of the "DefaultDomain" anywhere.